# css curtain effect without curtain having higher z-index?

Tags: css, z-index

http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_reveal/

The link above has the demo about what I'm trying to accomplish. However, the red curtain has higher z-index than ninja's in the demo. I need red curtain to be lower z-index than ninjas for other effects. How to emulate this effect? To clarify: I still want ninja's to get slowly uncovered like the demo, but I can't give them lower z-index than the red curtain.

Comment: You are using `background` there... use multiple background on the body i.e use gradient and ninja on the body tag itself

Comment: @Mr.Alien Can you please explain more? Also, see my edit... does your comment still apply?

Comment: I apologize, I just went through your demo again and I scrolled down, so its working fine, it's just that you should explain what you want to do exactly, as that is working absolutely fine

Comment: @tt:The trick used in the demo is called Parallax Scrolling.You can google it to learn more.Otherwise, `jsfiddle` would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes, the demo is working fine. I want to apply the same effect without using what they're using - giving higher z-index to curtain.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to explain this way, fiddle would be more appreciated.. but still

You are putting your ninja in body bg..

Now put your ninja into some `div`, say *div1*, then put this transparent image for ninja in *div1*,
keep `z-index` of *div1* above curtain's `z-index`